# 100K Semitec 104GT2 NTC thermistor

Tags: arduino

First of all, I'm new to the forum so I apologize if I opened this topic in the wrong place.
I want to control the hotend of my 3D printer using Arduino Nano. As a result of my research, I learned that "100K Semitec 104GT2 NTC thermistor" was used in the hotend. and accordingly I found that the beta coefficient of my thermistor is 4267K. I made my connections to A0 pin using a 4.7kohm resistor. I ran the system using the codes I shared below. However, the measured temperature value appears as 368.80 every time. What could be the problem and how can it be solved? I couldn't find any solution. I would be glad if you can help me.
hotend I use: "E3D-v6 HotEnd"

```
`#define THERMISTOR_PIN A0
#define SERIES_RESISTOR 4700  // 4.7 kohm resistor

// Steinhart-Hart coefficients for Semitec 104GT2 NTC Thermistor
#define A 0.001129148
#define B 0.0004267
#define C 0.0000000876741

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  // Measure the thermistor resistance
  int rawValue = analogRead(THERMISTOR_PIN);

  // Calculate the thermistor resistance
  float resistance = SERIES_RESISTOR / (1023.0 / rawValue - 1.0);

  // Calculate temperature using the Steinhart-Hart equation
  float steinhart;
  steinhart = resistance / 100000.0;     // (R/Ro)
  steinhart = log(steinhart);            // ln(R/Ro)
  steinhart /= B;                        // 1/B * ln(R/Ro)
  steinhart += 1.0 / (25 + 273.15);       // + (1/To)
  steinhart = 1.0 / steinhart;            // Invert
  steinhart -= 273.15;                    // Convert to Celsius

  // Print the obtained temperature value to the Serial Monitor
  Serial.print("Temperature: ");
  Serial.println(steinhart);

  delay(1000);
}`
```

Answer (score 1):

First on a minor suggestion on design change, you have a thermistor with 100k @25 degree Celsius, so it is better to have the serial resistor at the equal value of 100k instead of 4.7k, it will then put the reading in the mid range of the ADC scale at temperature 25 degree, which is not only a much more linear range of the ADC but also provides good range for measuring the temperature below and above 25 degree.

The formulas aren't correct. Let's break down step by step.

The Voltage at the analog pin A0 (let's called it Va) at the voltage divider that consists of a resistor (Rs and assumed of 100k instead of 4.7k) and the thermistor (Rt) can be derived with the following, with the assumption that the supply voltage is 5v (Vs):

```
voltage at Va:   Va = Vs * Rt/(Rs + Rt), or
                 Rt = Rs * Va/(Vs - Va)
```

The formula for temp in Kelvin according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermistor):

```
                 1
 T = ----------------------------
     1/To + (1/beta) * ln(Rt/Ro)

Where:
T: the temperature to be measured in Kelvin;
To: the reference temperature in Kelvin at 25 degree Celsius (i.e. 298.15);
Ro: the thermistor resistance at To(i.e. 100000);
B:  the Beta Coefficient provided by thermistor manufacturer(i.e. 4267).
```

We can now defines the constants and write some very simple program.

```cpp
const double Rs = 100000.0;   // voltage divider resistor value
const double Beta = 4267.0;   // Beta value
const double To = 298.15;     // Temperature in Kelvin for 25 degree Celsius
const double Ro = 100000.0;   // Resistance of Thermistor at 25 degree Celsius

const double adcMax = 1023.0; // ADC resolution 10-bit (0-1023)
const double Vs = 5.0;        // supply voltage

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(115200);
}

void loop() {
    double Va = analogRead(A0) * Vs/adcMax;
    double Rt = Rs * Va / (Vs - Va);
    double T = 1/(1/To + log(Rt/Ro)/Beta);  // Temperature in Kelvin
    double Tc = T - 273.15;                 // Celsius
    double Tf = Tc * 9 / 5 + 32;            // Fahrenheit
}
```

This will produce a temperature in Kevin at 298 when ADC value is 512, 0k when ADC=1023, and 578k when ADC=1.